# minimal polynomial is independent of choice of basis

Tags: linear-algebra, minimal-polynomials

Say I have a linear map $T:V\to V$, and two matrix representations, $M$, $N$, say, such that there exists an invertible matrix, $P$, with the same dimension and $M=P^{-1}NP$. Say $m_M$ and $m_N$ are minimal polynomials for $M$ and $N$. How would I show that $m_N(M)=0$?

Am I allowed to say that $m_N(M)=m_N(P^{-1}NP)= m_N(P^{-1})m_N(N)m_N(P)=0$ and that $m_M(N)=0$ follows similarly and hence the minimal polynomial is independent of choice of basis?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$M=P^{-1}NP$ implies $M^k=P^{-1}N^kP$ for all $k$ and so $f(M)=P^{-1}f(N)P$ for all polynomials $f$. Therefore, the set of polynomials that kill $M$ coincides with the set of polynomials that kill $N$.

Answer (score 1):

The way the question is phrased, I assume the intention was to bring $T$ into the argument in some way. And assuming that $M,N$ are matrices of $T$ with respect to two different bases (I think that is what you mean by "representation" here), that is indeed the simplest approach.

The crucial point is that one *can define* the minimal polynomial of $T$ itself, without ever using matrices: it is the minimal degree monic polynomial $X^d+c_{d-1}X^{d-1}+\cdots+c_1X+c_0$ such that one has
$$T^d+c_{d-1}T^{d-1}+\cdots+c_1T+c_0I=0\in\mathcal L(V,V).\tag1$$
(That some such monic polynomial exists is a consequence of the finite dimensionality of $\mathcal L(V,V)$, and that there is a unique one of minimal degree, which moreover divides all others, is the standard fact that every nonzero ideal of $K[X]$ has a unique monic generator; these arguments are identical for what one uses to define minimal polynomials of square matrices.)

What remains is to show that if $A$ is a matrix of $T$ with respect to some basis of$~V$ then $(1)$ is satisfied if and only if
$$A^d+c_{d-1}A^{d-1}+\cdots+c_1A+c_0I=0\in\operatorname{Mat}_{n,n}(K),\tag2$$
which is immediate from the way matrix arithmetic corresponds to arithmetic on linear operators. Then the minimal polynomial of $A$ is the same as that of $T$, and in the question $M,N$ are examples of such matrices$~A$.